# Updating to Windows 8 on dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, windows-8

I dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows Vista on separate partitions. I want to update Vista to Windows 8, but I'm worried that it will mess something up.

- How should I prepare for the update?
- How can I recover dual boot both to Ubuntu and Windows after update to Windows 8? (I assume that Windows still considers itself *"One OS to rule them all"* and wipes out other boot options without asking.)
- Are there any gotchas in general that I should be aware of?

**UPDATE**

So in the end, I didn't have to do *anything* after updating Windows :). After it installed and I restarted computer, I got the same boot menu as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade Windows, and then restore the bootloader.

1. Upgrade Windows as necessary. (Sorry, but we can't help with the specifics here)
2. If Ubuntu does not boot, insert the Ubuntu installation CD and boot from it.
3. Open the terminal and run

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Keep the terminal open and run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```
5. Follow the on-screen instructions. Do recommended repair, and remember the boot-info link it gives, in case there are deeper problems. If you do not have internet in the live CD, you can use the ISO [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk-17072012.iso/download).